# Can't install Doctrine DBAL using PEAR

Tags: doctrine, pear, dbal

When I try to install DoctrineDBAL using pear like:

```
C:\wamp\pear>pear install doctrine/DoctrineDBAL
```

I got the following error message:

> No releases available for package "pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineDBAL"
>   install failed

I also can't run `pear remote-list -c doctrine` command. I get a security error message (Possible symlink attack)

Any help is appreciated.

PS:Channel "pear.doctrine-project.org" is already initialized

Answer (score 0):

Try to **clear your cache**

```
pear clean-cache
```

then verify if you **detect the available version**:

```
pear remote-list -c doctrine
```

If you are having security errors **clean your temp files**
you can use [crapcleaner](http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/) to do this.

After this **try again** :

```
pear install doctrine/DoctrineDBAL
```

Or while you specify the version (2.3.0 is the latest version at the time this was written) :

```
pear install doctrine/DoctrineDBAL-2.3.6
```

It works all the time for me, hope it does for you